# How to select the last inserted records by date, time, minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, max

I have 4 records with the same CID# 201. I'm trying to get the last updated records by the second.  The issue it is returning all 4 of the records. I would like to return the last updated records by CID# 201. Here is my code.

```
 SELECT CID, to_char( max( UPDATED_DATE ), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )
 FROM mytable
 WHERE CID = 201;
```

This is the return records. **NOT DESIRED**

```
**`CID#`|   `UPDATED_DATE`**
 `201` | `03/30/2017 7:30:22`
 `201` | `03/30/2017 7:30:22`
 `201` | `03/30/2017 7:29:36`
 `201` | `03/30/2017 7:29:36`
```

This is what I want returned. **YES DESIRED**

```
**`CID`|   `UPDATED_DATE`**
 `201` | `03/30/2017 7:30:22`
 `201` | `03/30/2017 7:30:22`
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not even seem syntactically correct (it uses `MAX()` but lacks `GROUP BY`).  One method uses `rank()`:

```
 SELECT CID, to_char(UPDATED_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )
 FROM (SELECT t.*,
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY UPDATED_DATE DESC) as seqnum
       FROM mytable t
       WHERE CID = 201
      ) t
WHERE senqum = 1;
```

I should note that it seems strange that you want to return two identical rows.  You can include other columns in the above query.  Or, just do an aggregation:

```
SELECT CID, to_char(max(UPDATED_DATE ), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' ),
       COUNT(*) as numRecords
FROM mytable
WHERE CID = 201
GROUP BY CID;
```

Comment: I need the last inserted rows by updated_date and I need to return all rows with the ID 201, it is an array for checkboxes.  By the way it worked. Thank you

Comment: If the inner query has the `where` clause to select a single `CID`, then the `partition by` clause in the analytic function is not necessary. However, it will help if there's a need to select similar rows for more than one `CID` in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using newer Oracle versions, you can use `FETCH FIRST WITH TIES`!

```
SELECT CID, to_char(UPDATED_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') chardate
FROM mytable
WHERE CID = 201
order by chardate desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Comment: I really like 12c and FETCH FIRST ROWS ...  Here, I would sort on the date value itself and not the resulting character string.

Comment: @unleashed, sort by the date value itself is better as long as the to_char isn't meant to remove fractions of seconds. (Since I don't know if that happens here, I didn't dare to do that, to ensure no rows from same second was left out.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well.

```
select * from your_table 
where UPDATED_DATE in 
    (select max(UPDATED_DATE) 
    from your_table 
    where CID=201
    )
```

Comment: This is less efficient than using analytic functions (see Gordon's solution); actually this is exactly one of the main reasons Oracle introduced analytic functions many, many years ago. Yet a lot of developers are still not using them.

Comment: Actually, this will return all records with the updated date, but the user wants the records for the latest updated date AND CID = 201.  This could return values that are not CID = 201.